# Remove line breaks/newline characters from csv columns

Tags: python-3.x, dataframe, csv

I have a multiple csv in a folder. I wanted to merge them into one but I am getting error as some columns have carriage returns and hence I get error while I am trying merge them all into one.

My main problem is how to remove carriage returns from each csv and merge them all into one csv. Due to line breaks, my columns are also drifting and causing problem. Thanks.

```
  csv_list = glob.glob(os.path.join(path, "*.csv"))
  df = (pd.read_csv(f, sep=',') for f in csv_list )
  df_merged   = pd.concat(df, ignore_index=True)   
  df_merged.to_csv("merged_raw.csv")
```

Answer (score 1):

To remove whitespace and carriage returns in the .csv files, you can read them all, clean them, then write them back with:

```py
csv_list = glob.glob(os.path.join(path, "*.csv"))
for csv in csv_list:
    with open(csv, 'r') as f:
        raw_csv = f.read()
        clean_csv = raw_csv.strip()
    
    with open(csv, 'w') as f:
        f.write(clean_csv)
```

To remove all types of whitespace in your dataframe, including carriage returns, you can use something like:

```py
df_merged.applymap(lambda x: x.strip if isinstance(x, str) else x)
```

Comment: Thanks for you reply. I am not able to merge csv and getting error. That's because each csv file, has some columns which has line breaks. Hence I need to find a way to remove line breaks or carriage returns before I load them into dataframe and then merge them.

Comment: @Lilly try using the edited first solution, that will clean the text files before you import them into pandas.

Comment: Thanks. I tried. Still it hasn't remove line breaks/newline characters from columns. "\n" is in few columns and not at the end of each line. That's bit tricky.

Comment: I get the following error when tried merging them. pandas.errors.ParserError: Error tokenizing data. C error: Expected 17 fields in line 198, saw 18

Comment: @Lilly Could there be an extra comma in one of the rows? The error seems to indicate that. I would manually check line 198 to make sure that the data is as expected. Hope this is helpful.

Comment: its due to a "\n" in few columns. Hence extra comma is introduced. How to remove them. Thanks.

Comment: @Lilly Why would a `\n` introduce a comma? If you `strip()` the strings as I have shown above you shouldn't have trailing newlines or whitespaces. Open up a text editor and look in your file to make sure your data is correct.

Comment: Hi @vtasca, When I open up the data in text editor it's as follows.  header:  ID, name, description, qty, price                                         Line1:    1,  pen,  good quality, 4, 5.50                                              Line2:    2,  book, Good read and\, must, 5, 10

Comment: In the line2, I see "\" which is creating problem and adding extra comma in the dataset. How do I deal with this. not sure. 1st row has 5 columns and 2nd row has 6 columns. Thats how it is in the text editor when I open. Thanks.